# detect text in passport images with opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am detecting text from various passport images with OpenCV. The task is to get the cropped text present on passports like Name, DOB, Nationality, etc. The current code is given below:

```
image = cv2.imread(image) # read image
image = imutils.resize(image, height=600)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)

rectKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (13, 5))
sqKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (21, 21))
blackhat = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_BLACKHAT, rectKernel)

gradX = cv2.Sobel(blackhat, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=-1)
gradX = np.absolute(gradX)
(minVal, maxVal) = (np.min(gradX), np.max(gradX))
gradX = (255 * ((gradX - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal))).astype("uint8")

gradX = cv2.morphologyEx(gradX, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, rectKernel)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gradX, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

if do_erosion: # do erosion if flag is True only
    thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, sqKernel)
    thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, None, iterations=4)
p = int(image.shape[1] * 0.05)
thresh[:, 0:p] = 0
thresh[:, image.shape[1] - p:] = 0   # thresholded image shown below

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)   # finding contours from threshold image
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
rois=[]
# loop over the contours
for c in cnts:
    # compute the bounding box of the contour and use the contour to
    # compute the aspect ratio and coverage ratio of the bounding box
    # width to the width of the image
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ar = w / float(h)
    crWidth = w / float(gray.shape[1])
    # check to see if the aspect ratio and coverage width are within
    # acceptable criteria
    
    if ar > 2 and crWidth > 0.05:
        # pad the bounding box since we applied erosions and now need
        # to re-grow it
        pX = int((x + w) * 0.03)
        pY = int((y + h) * 0.03)
        (x, y) = (x - pX, y - pY)
        (w, h) = (w + (pX * 2), h + (pY * 2))
        # extract the ROI from the image and draw a bounding box
        # surrounding the MRZ
        roi = original[y:y + h, x:x + w].copy()  # interested in finding all ROIs having text
        rois.append(roi)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

I am detecting some textual values correctly but the solution is not generic. It is sometimes extracting only the year of DOB but not the full date (sometimes it detects month and day as well but not in the same ROI). The original and threshold image is shown below:

[image: original image]

[image: threshold image]

[image: ROIs detected on image,]

As you can see, in the "ROIs found image" some ROIs are not being detected in the same image like DOB and date of expiry. Any help in extracting all the text regions from the passport will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tweak the Aspect Ratio and Coverage ratio thresholds to obtain all the desired bounding boxes.
When I run your code, for `05`, the value of `ar` is `1.541` and value of `crWidth`  is `0.03`. Since these values are less than the thresholds you have specified, they are getting filtered out. This is why some of the words do not have bounding boxes in the final image.

But, since you want to get the entire DOB in a single bounding box, just before the line `thresh[:, 0:p] = 0`, you can apply a dilation operation:
`thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, np.ones((1, 30), np.uint8))`.

This will dilate the pixels and combine blobs that are nearby horizontally. The resultant image after preprocessing is as follows -
[image]

The final image -
[image]

Comment: thanks, it is solving the problem for this particular passport picture, but if I would like to have a generic solution will it be possible to tweak the values to find every ROI for the texts?

Comment: @Asim You could run this algorithm on a bunch of passport images, and analyse the results. Then we could look at possible ways to generalize the solution.

Comment: ,thanks for the help! I am currently running it on various passports and in some passports '2' aspect ratio is giving good results and sometimes 1.5. Maybe I need a model after extracting the ROIs to analyze if the ROI is "complete and acceptable" or a tweak is needed.

Comment: get error when run above code. "if do_erosion:" and "original" words show red line in pycharm. please guide me.